# Order by where condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have the following query:

```
select `state` from `table1` 
where `state` in ('NC','North Carolina','TN','Tennessee','CO','Colorado','NM','New Mexico','UT','Utah')
limit 200 offset 0
```

I need the results ordered by `state` as they appear in my `where` clause (i.e. first `NC`, then `TN`, then `CO`, and so on).

How can I do this? I tried using `order by` but it doesn't give this result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use **[`ORDER BY FIELD`](http://www.imthi.com/blog/programming/mysql-order-by-field-custom-field-sorting.php)**

```
SELECT `state`
FROM `table1`
WHERE `state` IN ('NC','North Carolina','TN','Tennessee','CO','Colorado','NM','New Mexico','UT','Utah')
ORDER BY FIELD(`state`, 'NC','North Carolina','TN','Tennessee','CO','Colorado','NM','New Mexico','UT','Utah');
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92a16d/2)

Comment: can't you see the tag `MySQL`?

Comment: @Mortalus The question has the `mysql` tag

Comment: Is there any way to reuse the list of values from the `IN` clause?

Comment: @Asad what do you mean by *reuse*? :D

Comment: @JohnWoo I just mean is there any way to not have to write it out again.

Comment: @Asad maybe by using *parameters*

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT col_name
FROM table_nane
WHERE col_nane IN ('NC','North Carolina','TN','Tennessee','CO','Colorado','NM','New Mexico','UT','Utah')
ORDER BY FIELD(`state`, 'NC',.....);
```

and so on....

Comment: You should indent your query by four spaces, so that it will be shown as code

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
order by case when `state`='NC' or `state`='North Carolina' then 1 
              when `state`='TN' or `state`='Tennessee' then 2
              when `state`='CO' or `state`='Colorado' then 3
         end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `ORDER BY` with a `CASE WHEN` construct:

```
ORDER BY CASE 
            WHEN state = 'NC' THEN 1
            WHEN state = 'North Carolina' THEN 2
            ...
         END
```